# How to link to specific variable with this code?

Tags: php, variables, yii

I have a piece of code, and I can't work out how to link it to a specific page,

Basically I want the link  to link to a variable after page.

At present it works and links to www.mysite/page/ as i want it to I just want www.mysite/page/SOME VARIABLE

for example:

There seem to be a couple of variables in the code, but I can't seem to make one work. Any ideas, I don't mind which it links to, as long as its unique for each occurrence.

Hope this makes a little bit of sense

Code:

```
> <div class='txt-center'>  <h3><?php echo $this->t('{num}
> Entries',array('{num}'=>CHtml::tag('span', array('class'=>'bought'),
> $bought))); ?></h3>   <h4><?php echo $this->t('This competition is
> over.'); ?><br><?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('/page/')); ?>
>   
> 
> 
>   <?php if($this->deal->cacheValue('tippedTime')) { ?>    <div>       <?php
> echo $this->t('Tipped at {time} with {num} bought', array(            '{time}'
> => app()->getDateFormatter()->formatDateTime(utime($this->deal->cacheValue('tippedTime'),false),
> null),            '{num}' => $this->deal->cacheValue('tippedAmount')          
>       )); ?>  </div>  <?php } ?> </div>
```

Comment: It's like you just threw PHP at the wall.

Comment: @DigitalChris 'the wall' is being nice